# Navigation in Xamarin.forms: buffer null

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation

In a Xamarin.Forms app, I have a button on a `Page` (**Page_1**) that sends me to another `Page` (**Page_2**) with the statement

```cs
await Navigation.PushAsync (new Page_2 ());
```

On this `Page`, I have several `ImageButton`s that all return me to **Page_1** when clicked with the statement

```cs
await Navigation.PopAsync ();
```

This works the first time around, but the second time I press the button on the **Page_1**, I go to the **Page_2**, then when I click on an `ImageButton` the application quits with the error message:

> System.ArgumentNullException
> Message = Buffer cannot be null.
> Parameter name: buffer

How can I make the `Navigation.NavigationStack` still contain the **Page_1**?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Add for  Deczaloth  : this is the partial code of the first page :

```
private async void btnModifImage_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string imgLocation;
        // affichage et choix : gallerie ou internet
        imgLocation = await DisplayActionSheet("Emplacement", "Annuler", null, imageLocation);
        if (imgLocation == "Gallerie")
        {
            // chargement image depuis gallerie
            imageChanged = true;
            article_nomcat = pickerCat.Title;
            article_unit = pickerUnit.Title;
            try
            {
                FileData fileData = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
                //
                var filepath = fileData.FilePath;
                //
                if (fileData == null)
                    return; // user canceled file picking

                newimageByte = fileData.DataArray;
                resizedImageByte = await ImageResizer.ResizeImage(newimageByte, 100, 100);

                if (resizedImageByte != null)
                {
                    imageChanged = true;
                    var stream1 = new MemoryStream(resizedImageByte);
                    ImageArticle.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream1);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                imageChanged = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            App.ImageName = name.Text;
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ImageBingPage());
        }
    }
```

and the partial code of the second page ImageBingPage :

```
private async void img1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] img1Byte = await DownloadImageAsync(img1Path);
        App.imgByte = img3Byte;
        await Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
```

And the biginning of the second page :

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        SearchImage();
        base.OnDisappearing();
    }

    public void SearchImage()
    {
        
        List<Images> imageList = new List<Images>();
        SearchResult bingResult = BingImageSearch(App.ImageName);
        var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(bingResult.jsonResult);
        for (int i = 0; i < res.value.Count; i++)
        {
            imageList.Add(new Images { ImagePath = res.value[i].contentUrl });
        }
        img1.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(imageList[0].ImagePath));
        img1Path = imageList[0].ImagePath;
        img2.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(imageList[1].ImagePath));
        img2Path = imageList[1].ImagePath;
        img3.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(imageList[2].ImagePath));
        img3Path = imageList[2].ImagePath;
    }

    static SearchResult BingImageSearch(string searchQuery)
    {
        var uriQuery = baseURl + "?q=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(searchQuery);
        WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uriQuery);
        request.Headers["Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"] = APIKey;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponseAsync().Result;
        string json = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        var searchResult = new SearchResult();
        searchResult.jsonResult = json;
        searchResult.relevantHeaders = new Dictionary<String, String>();
        foreach (String header in response.Headers)
        {
            if (header.StartsWith("BingAPIs-") || header.StartsWith("X-MSEdge-"))
                searchResult.relevantHeaders[header] = response.Headers[header];
        }
        return searchResult;
    }


    async Task<byte[]> DownloadImageAsync(string imageUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var httpResponse = await _httpClient.GetAsync(imageUrl))
            {
                if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    return await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    //Url is Invalid
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Handle Exception
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Add 2 for Deczaloth : You're right: the stack is not empty (see the two attached screenshots). So where does the problem come from?
[image: First pass]
[image: Second pzass]

Edit for Jack : I have modified my code to simplify the problem:

```
private async void img1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //byte[] img1Byte = await DownloadImageAsync(imgPath[0]);
        //App.imgByte = img1Byte;
        await Navigation.PopAsync();
    }

    private async void img2_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //byte[] img2Byte = await DownloadImageAsync(imgPath[1]);
        //App.imgByte = img2Byte;
        await Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
```

And now I can do 3 round trips between the ArticleEntry page and the ImageBingPage page, but after, the app crashes anyway.

Edit for Jack : there is the code on the page ArticleEntry :

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        if (App.AddArticle == true)
        {
            ToolbarItems.Remove(btnDelete);
        }
        
        //
        _article = (Article)BindingContext;
        old_article_ID = _article.ID;
        old_article_name = _article.Name;
        article_nomcat = _article.NomCat;
        article_unit = _article.UniteMesure;
        //
        if (_article.ID == 0)
        {
            name.Focus();
        }
        //
        if (pickerCat.Title != null & pickerCat.Title != "choisissez une catégorie")
        {
            _article.NomCat = pickerCat.Title;
            pickerCat.TitleColor = Color.Black;
        }
        else
        {
            if (_article.NomCat != null)
            {
                pickerCat.Title = _article.NomCat;
                pickerCat.SelectedItem = _article.NomCat;
                pickerCat.TitleColor = Color.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                pickerCat.Title = "choisissez une catégorie";
                pickerCat.TitleColor = Color.Gray;
            }
            
        }
        //
        if (pickerUnit.Title != null & pickerUnit.Title != "choisissez une unité de mesure")
        {
            _article.UniteMesure = pickerUnit.Title;
            pickerUnit.TitleColor = Color.Black;
        }
        else
        {
            if (_article.UniteMesure != null)
            {
                pickerUnit.Title = _article.UniteMesure;
                pickerUnit.SelectedItem = _article.UniteMesure;
                pickerUnit.TitleColor = Color.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                pickerUnit.Title = "choisissez une unité de mesure";
                pickerUnit.TitleColor = Color.Gray;
            }
        }
        //
        if (pickerListeAchats.Title != null & pickerListeAchats.Title != "choisissez une liste d'achats")
        {
            //_article.UniteMesure = pickerUnit.Title;
            pickerListeAchats.TitleColor = Color.Black;
        }
        
        //
        ReadAllCategorieList dbcategorie = new ReadAllCategorieList();
        DB_CategorieList = dbcategorie.GetAllCategorie(); //Get all DB Categorie
        // trier  
        DB_CategorieList_Sorted = DB_CategorieList.OrderBy(i => i.NomCat).ToList();
        //
        // rempliir la liste du picker Cat
        string[] pickerListCat;
        List<string> pkListCat = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in DB_CategorieList_Sorted)
        {
            string element = item.NomCat;
            //pickerCat.Items.Add(element);
            pkListCat.Add(element);
        }
        pickerListCat = pkListCat.ToArray();
        pickerCat.ItemsSource = pickerListCat;
        //
        // rempliir la liste du picker Unit
        ReadAllUnitList dbunit = new ReadAllUnitList();
        DB_UnitList = dbunit.GetAllUnit();
        // trier  
        DB_UnitList_Sorted = DB_UnitList.OrderBy(i => i.UniteMesure).ToList();
        //
        List<string> pickerListUnit = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in DB_UnitList_Sorted)
        {
            string element = item.UniteMesure;
            pickerListUnit.Add(element);
        }
        pickerUnit.ItemsSource = pickerListUnit;
        //
        // remplir la liste du picker ListeAchats
        ReadAllListeAchatsList dblisteachats = new ReadAllListeAchatsList();
        DB_ListeAchatsList = dblisteachats.GetAllListeAchats();
        // trier  
        DB_ListeAchatsList_Sorted = DB_ListeAchatsList.OrderBy(i => i.NomListe).ToList();
        //
        List<string> pickerListAchat = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in DB_ListeAchatsList_Sorted)
        {
            string element = item.NomListe;
            pickerListAchat.Add(element);
        }
        pickerListeAchats.ItemsSource = pickerListAchat;
        //
        //
        imageByte = _article.ImageArt;
        //
        // convertir le byte[] en bitmapimage (si != 0)
        if (_article.ImageArt != null)
        {
            if (imageChanged)
            {
                var stream1 = new MemoryStream(newimageByte);
                ImageArticle.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream1);
            }
            else
            {
                var stream1 = new MemoryStream(imageByte);
                ImageArticle.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (imageChanged == false)
            {
                imageByte = ImageDataFromResource("MemoCourses.Assets.Images.appareil_photo.png");
                var stream1 = new MemoryStream(imageByte);
                ImageArticle.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream1);
            }
        }
        //
        if (App.imgByte != null)
        {
            resizedImageByte = await ImageResizer.ResizeImage(App.imgByte, 100, 100);
            if (resizedImageByte != null)
            {
                imageChanged = true;
                var stream1 = new MemoryStream(resizedImageByte);
                ImageArticle.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream1);
            }
        }
        //
        base.OnDisappearing();
        App.AddArticle = false;
    }
```

Code changed based on Jack's comments

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        if (App.AddArticle == true)
        {
            ToolbarItems.Remove(btnDelete);
        }
        //
        _article = (Article)BindingContext;
        old_article_ID = _article.ID;
        old_article_name = _article.Name;
        article_nomcat = _article.NomCat;
        article_unit = _article.UniteMesure;
        //
        if (_article.ID == 0)
        {
            name.Focus();
        }
        //
        if (pickerCat.Title != null & pickerCat.Title != "choisissez une catégorie")
        {
            _article.NomCat = pickerCat.Title;
            pickerCat.TitleColor = Color.Black;
        }
        else
        {
            if (_article.NomCat != null)
            {
                pickerCat.Title = _article.NomCat;
                pickerCat.SelectedItem = _article.NomCat;
                pickerCat.TitleColor = Color.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                pickerCat.Title = "choisissez une catégorie";
                pickerCat.TitleColor = Color.Gray;
            }
            
        }
        //
        if (pickerUnit.Title != null & pickerUnit.Title != "choisissez une unité de mesure")
        {
            _article.UniteMesure = pickerUnit.Title;
            pickerUnit.TitleColor = Color.Black;
        }
        else
        {
            if (_article.UniteMesure != null)
            {
                pickerUnit.Title = _article.UniteMesure;
                pickerUnit.SelectedItem = _article.UniteMesure;
                pickerUnit.TitleColor = Color.Black;
            }
            else
            {
                pickerUnit.Title = "choisissez une unité de mesure";
                pickerUnit.TitleColor = Color.Gray;
            }
        }
        //
        if (pickerListeAchats.Title != null & pickerListeAchats.Title != "choisissez une liste d'achats")
        {
            pickerListeAchats.TitleColor = Color.Black;
        }
        
        //
        ReadAllCategorieList dbcategorie = new ReadAllCategorieList();
        DB_CategorieList = dbcategorie.GetAllCategorie(); //Get all DB Categorie
        // trier  
        DB_CategorieList_Sorted = DB_CategorieList.OrderBy(i => i.NomCat).ToList();
        //
        // rempliir la liste du picker Cat
        string[] pickerListCat;
        List<string> pkListCat = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in DB_CategorieList_Sorted)
        {
            string element = item.NomCat;
            pkListCat.Add(element);
        }
        pickerListCat = pkListCat.ToArray();
        pickerCat.ItemsSource = pickerListCat;
        //
        // rempliir la liste du picker Unit
        ReadAllUnitList dbunit = new ReadAllUnitList();
        DB_UnitList = dbunit.GetAllUnit();
        // trier  
        DB_UnitList_Sorted = DB_UnitList.OrderBy(i => i.UniteMesure).ToList();
        //
        List<string> pickerListUnit = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in DB_UnitList_Sorted)
        {
            string element = item.UniteMesure;
            pickerListUnit.Add(element);
        }
        pickerUnit.ItemsSource = pickerListUnit;
        //
        // remplir la liste du picker ListeAchats
        ReadAllListeAchatsList dblisteachats = new ReadAllListeAchatsList();
        DB_ListeAchatsList = dblisteachats.GetAllListeAchats();
        // trier  
        DB_ListeAchatsList_Sorted = DB_ListeAchatsList.OrderBy(i => i.NomListe).ToList();
        //
        List<string> pickerListAchat = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in DB_ListeAchatsList_Sorted)
        {
            string element = item.NomListe;
            pickerListAchat.Add(element);
        }
        pickerListeAchats.ItemsSource = pickerListAchat;
        //
        //
        imageByte = _article.ImageArt;
        //
        // convertir le byte[] en bitmapimage (si != 0)
        if (_article.ImageArt != null)
        {
            if (imageGallery)
            {
                var stream1 = new MemoryStream(resizedImageByte);
                ImageArticle.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream1);
            }
            else
            {
                if (App.imgByte == null)
                {
                    // image depuis la base SQLite
                    var stream1 = new MemoryStream(imageByte);
                    ImageArticle.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream1);
                }
                else
                {
                    // image depuis internet
                    var stream1 = new MemoryStream(App.imgByte);
                    ImageArticle.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream1);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (imageChanged == false)
            {
                // image par défaut
                imageByte = ImageDataFromResource("MemoCourses.Assets.Images.appareil_photo.png");
                var stream1 = new MemoryStream(imageByte);
                ImageArticle.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream1);
            }
        }
        //
        if (App.imgByte != null & imageInternet == true)
        {
            resizedImageByte = await ImageResizer.ResizeImage(App.imgByte, 100, 100);
            if (resizedImageByte != null)
            {
                var stream1 = new MemoryStream(resizedImageByte);
                ImageArticle.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream1);
            }
        }
        //
        base.OnDisappearing();
        App.AddArticle = false;
        imageGallery = false;
        imageInternet = false;
    }
```

Comment: The exception does not look like saying there is a problem with the NavigationStack. The issue should be somewhere else. Can you share further details? I created a simple solution that does only what you described (going from one page to the other and back), but i do not get any exception...

Comment: I added a few lines of code to better understand how the error occurs. What reminds me of a navigation problem is that if I leave the ArticleEntry page after adding the image and then come back to that page and change the image again, I don't have this mistake. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: I'm sending you a link https://1drv.ms/t/s!Am0yZGVkguZvjqV5tP0gCFIdg1JUxQ?e=uwokAb  to open the stacktrace - hope that's what you're asking me. If not, tell me how I can get it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not caused by the `NavigationStack`.

1.You should not call `base.OnDisappearing();` in `OnAppearing`:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    SearchImage();
    //remove this line
    //base.OnDisappearing();
}
```

2.You get a `java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to aardbeienzo.com not permitted` which you does not have permission to load url start with http:

Go to Android project --> Properties --> Assemblyinfo.cs, add `UsesCleartextTraffic = true`:

```
// Add some common permissions, these can be removed if not needed
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.Internet)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage)]

[assembly: Application(UsesCleartextTraffic = true)]
```

Update:

```
private async void img1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] img1Byte = await DownloadImageAsync(img1Path);
        //App.imgByte = img3Byte;
        App.imgByte = img1Byte;
        await Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
```

**Update 2:**

Generally, If you use Navigation push/pop correctly, it will not cause the error. Pay attention to the OnAppearing method of Page and check the code there.

The correct code has been updated in the question by `Marcel Delhaye`.

Comment: Hello Jack, I applied your changes, and one of the two problems is resolved: all mages are now displayed correctly. However, the application still crashes when I return to the ArticleEntry page by clicking on an imagebutton with the instruction :
 await Navigation.PopAsync ();
Here is the link to view the stacktrace: [link] 
 https://1drv.ms/t/s!Am0yZGVkguZvjqV6FDE9mD2mQ3btpA?e=toFT7r
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: PS: this is the stack trace after the first return: in this case, the application does not crash
[link] https://1drv.ms/t/s!Am0yZGVkguZvjqV7bL_jQfv1uhrW_Q?e=msF0P3

Comment: Another additional information: when I click the second time on the edit image button from the ArticleEntry page, then while on the ImageBingPage page, that I click on the back arrow instead of clicking on an imagebutton, I have the same result: the application crash.

Comment: There is another exception in your stack trace: `System.InvalidCastException: Impossible d'effectuer un cast d'un objet de type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.PointerValue' en type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.PrimitiveValue'.`

Comment: See my updated answer, you want to assign img1Byte to  App.imgByte instead of  img3Byte, right?

Comment: Yes, if the user changes his mind: after choosing an image, he realizes that the choice is not good, so he clicks again on the Edit image button of the ArticleEntry page, he arrives to the second time on the ImageBingPage, and he clicks on the imagebutton img1 (instead of img3 the first time). This is when the application crashes and the error message appears.
Unfortunately, I don't understand the message ` System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast an object of type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.PointerValue' to type 'Mono.Debugger.Soft.PrimitiveValue' '. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't understand what to change in my code.

Comment: Excuse me Jack, I hadn't seen the update, but anyway, it was a typo that I corrected before you answered. This does not solve my problem.

Comment: Are you getting null in the DownloadImageAsync?

Comment: No, as you can see in the update, I deleted both command lines
img2Byte = null;
img2Byte = await DownloadImageAsync (imgPath [1]);
and that doesn't change anything. The buffer error is still there when I return to the ArticleEntry page. You can see the DownloadImageAsync stack trace (imgPath [1] here: [link] https://1drv.ms/t/s!Am0yZGVkguZvjqgL5SQX9gT-9v445g?e=6fBkEp

Comment: Is there any code in OnAppearing method in Page1? It's not caused by navigation and it may caused by loading something in OnAppearing method when you go back.

Comment: Sorry for my late response, I have been busy until now. Yes, there are even a lot of lines, I'll copy them to you in the description of the problem. I run the program and debug this code. I'll give you the result in a moment.

Comment: You are right, the error comes from 'protected override async void OnAppearing ()' of the AricleEntry page: I did not modify it to take into account the choice of the image on the Internet. I correct and publish the modified code as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks, thanks a lot Jack. I modified the code of the method
protected override async void OnAppearing () of the ArticleEntry page
to take into account the choice of image on the internet, and now everything is working perfectly. I posted the modified code in the question. I let you rephrase your last comment as an answer, and I will validate it.
Thank you again for your patience and the help you gave me.

Comment: I updated my answer and please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: Thanks Jack. It's important to be able to count on experienced developers like you. I accepted your answer as the solution to my problem.